# How to add hreflang in TPL format of Prestashop

Tags: url, parameters, meta-tags, prestashop-1.7, lang

I have a multilingual website, in order to optimize SEO, I want to add "hreflang" meta tags in the header.

The languages are organized in sub-folders like :

- **www.example.com/en**
- **www.example.com/fr**
- **www.example.com/de**

and so on...
So I want to retrieve the languages sub-folder information into the tag :

```
**<link rel="alternate" hreflang="$insert_language_of_current_page" href="www.example.com/en">**
```

But i'm not very familiar with the TPL format of Prestashop.
Is there already a parameter to do that ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module, it adds the href langs rel to your shop automatically:
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/seo-natural-search-engine-optimization/40888-seo-smo-assistant.html

If you want to do it yourself, for PrestaShop 1.7 find this file:

themes/[Your Theme]/templates/_partials/head.tpl

add this code to the end of the file:

```
{foreach from=$urls.alternative_langs item=pageUrl key=code}
   <link rel="alternate" href="{$pageUrl}" hreflang="{$code}">
{/foreach}
```

For PS1.6 you need to find this file:

themes/[Your Theme]/header.tpl

Inside this file put the code bellow before the `</head>` tag:

```
{if isset($language_code) && $language_code}
{foreach from=$languages key=k item=language name="languages"}
    {if $language.iso_code == $lang_iso}
        <!-- Current lang -->
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" href="{if isset($force_ssl) && $force_ssl}{$base_dir_ssl|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$base_dir|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}">
    {/if}
{/foreach}
<!-- Other langs (if exist) -->
{foreach from=$languages key=k item=language name="languages"}
    {if $language.iso_code != $lang_iso}
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" href="{if isset($force_ssl) && $force_ssl}{$base_dir_ssl|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$base_dir|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}{$language.iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}/">
    {/if}
{/foreach}
{/if}
```